# How to use Bitlocker encryption with Windows Server 2008R2 native disk backup

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, encryption, bitlocker

I'm looking to use BitLocker encryption on my backup disks, used with the native Windows Server backup feature, in 2008R2 server.

I'm using BitLocker on all the drives in the system, but the backup drive is not visible in Windows Explorer (which I know is by design) nor is it visible in the BitLocker console. I've looked here, and on the web, and don't seem to be able to find an answer. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use Disk Management to assign a drive letter (not necessary, though much easier than alternatives; also can be done via `diskpart`). Use the normal BitLocker GUIs or `manage-bde` to enable BL.

Comment: I got that far, thanks, but haven't yet been able to get the OS to treat the drive as an internal. It's an external USB drive. Any thoughts on how I might get that working?

Comment: Unfortunately BL doesn't actually care what kind of drive it is, but the GUI sometimes does. The command line version (`manage-bde`) should work on any partitioned disk however.